# How to use comma around mathematical symbols?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am having trouble determining the correct use of comma when specifying mathematical symbols, and the literature that I follow does not seem to be consistent. Which of the following would be correct usage of comma and why? The symbol *C<sub>D</sub>* refers to drag coefficient.

> - The enhancement of drag coefficient, *C<sub>D</sub>,* is partly due to the offshore flow over limited fetch.
> - The enhancement of drag coefficient *C<sub>D</sub>* is partly due to the offshore flow over limited fetch.
> - The enhancement of drag coefficient, *C<sub>D</sub>* is partly due to the offshore flow over limited fetch.

The reason for specifying both the quantity name and its mathematical symbol is because the sentence references an element in a figure.

Comment: The answer depends on what CD relates to: I guess it's the drag coefficient. If that's the symbol for the enhancement of the coefficient then the answer won't be the same.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for prompt reply, please see my edit.

Comment: I would favor the second, comma-less version, but particularly when the C<sub>D</sub> part is present in the sentence because that is the version that serves as a label in the figure, putting it in parentheses might be the best solution.

Comment: Your third version is wrong.  Either of the first two are acceptable, but I would prefer parentheses around Cd, rather than commas.

Comment: This is off topic. Maybe try [writers.se] or [academia.se].

Comment: http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/dragco.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the second one best, hands down.  This choice comes up in non-mathematical contexts too: *My brother Billy is coming with us*.  Yes, you could write *My brother, Billy, is coming with us*.  But there's no need.  In a more complex sentence, the commas can be helpful, but here, and in your sentence, they just drag us down.